# How to change excel timestamp format ? Format change but date is not correct

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel

```
$my = '13/02/2022 21:29:30';
$converted = date('d M Y h.i.s A', strtotime($my));
$reversed = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($converted));
echo $reversed;
```

// output
01-01-1970 00:00:00

but I want a correct date

Answer (score 0):

you can use several solution .

**solution #1**

```
$var = '20/04/2012 21:29:30';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $var);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

**solution #2**

```
$old_date = explode('/', '5/4/2010'); 
$new_data = $old_date[2].'-'.$old_date[1].'-'.$old_date[0];
```

**solution #3**

```
$var = '20/04/2012';
echo implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $var)));
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a DateTime Object from the string.
- Then format the date!!
- **Happy Coding‍!**

```
$my = '13/02/2022 21:29:30';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $my);
echo $date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```